# How to hide physical path for images and files in symfony2

Tags: symfony, url-rewriting, symfony-2.1

I've got to read and serve a lot of resources (images and files) and I want to hide real path where resources are stored. What is the best way to do it with symfony 2.x?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to abstract from the filesystem you could use [KnpGaufretteBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle). Gaufrette is a PHP library that abstracts the filesystem. That is, you can access resources no matter where they are stored (e.g., the local filesystem, a FTP server, Amazon S3, Dropbox, etc).

However, Gaufrette does not abstract the path (you set up a kind of base directory for the filesystem) and you would use a path relative to this base directory. Consider the following code that abstracts the local filesystem:

```
<?php

use Gaufrette\Filesystem;
use Gaufrette\Adapter\Local as LocalAdapter;

$adapter = new LocalAdapter('/var/media');
$filesystem = new Filesystem($adapter):

$content = $filesystem->read('myFile.txt');

$content = 'Hello I am the new content';

$filesystem->write('myFile.txt', $content);
```

In this example you would read and write the file */var/media/myFile.txt*.

If you want to further abstract the filesystem, you could create a service that has a map of files and its aliases. For example, you could read a list of these file/alias pairs from a YAML configuration file. You can then get the *real* filename by using some kind of getter with the alias as parameter.